# Why am i unable to run docker image by its name?

Tags: docker

I have a really simple docker file, and i am running docker 20.10.7:

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update

COPY flag.txt /root/myflag.txt
```

And i  build the image:

```
$ sudo docker build -t one:1 .
```

And look for images:

```
$ sudo docker images
REPOSITORY   TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED          SIZE
one          1         4a12e8fa8a37   36 seconds ago   166MB
ubuntu       16.04     b6f507652425   3 months ago     135MB
```

And now I want to run it.  In a video [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ClGmDq-3ujM), it looks like I am able to just refer to the image by its name, like this:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm one
Unable to find image 'one:latest' locally
docker: Error response from daemon: pull access denied for one, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied.
See 'docker run --help'.
```

But this fails, it just doesnt know what to look for. I instead use the id, which works:

```
$ sudo docker run -it --rm 4a12e8fa8a37
```

But why can't I use the name, as is done in the video i linked? it would be a lot easier

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to either build your image without tag (`:latest` will be assigned automatically)

```
docker build -t one .
```

or run it with your specific tag

```
docker run -it --rm one:1
```